# Passing arguments to commands for NRPE Exporter for Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, nrpe

I am using NRPE exporter https://github.com/canonical/nrpe_exporter and it works well for the commands that do not need arguments (e.g. check_cpu) but i cannot figure out how to pass arguments to the command (e.g. check_load -w 5,5,5 -c 9,9,9). I am particulary referring to the prometheus config.

```
 params:
  command: [check_load]
  ssl: [true]
```

I tried with ["check_load -w 5,5,5 -c 9,9,9"] but then the whole string is treated an a command to execute and it fails.

Any one successfully used the NRPE exporter for prometheus for commands that require arguments? The example config in the above git repo uses check_load without arguments and I get the above error. Thanks

Comment: See [NRPE Arguments](https://github.com/canonical/nrpe_exporter/issues/12)